# Hide loading icon when all children are rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some trivial (I guess) problem regarding rendering in react but can not solve it and can not find any solution.

My problem is that I have component which is wrapper for some entries. Something like:

```
class MyWrapper extends Component {
  renderItems() {
    return (
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
         <ItemComponent item={item} />
        ))}
    );
  }

  renderMessage() {
    return (<p>No items to show</p>);
  }

  render() {
   <div>
     {this.props.length
        ? this.renderItems()
        : this.renderMessage()
     } 
   </div>
  }
}
```

Usually I got in `this.props.items` bunch of items so render all of theme took a time. This is why I would like to show message like `Loading items...` until render all items is finished. Then this message should disappear.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Also, please post the entire component's code.

Comment: @Rahamin I receive array of items as property from parent component. Apart of that that is all.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Rahamin he wants a loader while the map is being processed

Comment: I understood that :)  So the problem is that the loader is not displayed? Or anything else?

Comment: @Rahamin The problem is how to detect when all <ItemComponent> are rendered. Then I could hide the loader.

Comment: Why not just preload it with a loading spinner, then start loading the items in the `componentDidMount` to force the re-render.  Although, honestly, I'm not sure even this will work-- you're not asking for a loading indicator from some async process, but for the react lifecycle itself-- might not be possible...

Comment: @AlexanderNied I suppose it won't work. `componentDidMount` is called just after wrapper component did mount but still before render all of ItemComponents.

Comment: When this.props.length is not zero, are all items already in the array? Are they received at once?

Comment: @Rahamin yes, all items are in the array.

Comment: Then why should it take time to render all of them? Do you see that they render slowly? If so, then it is obvious that rendering is in process, and there is no need for the 'loading' message.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. In the array are number of items ~500. Each `ItemComponent` has some quite simple logic but still couple of element to render. So yeah, it took a time until items appear. So I want then show Loading message/Loading spinner/Whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just my experiments how to do - I would suggest to take some ideas and try it out yourself, maybe it will get you on a right track or maybe this is baloney

https://codesandbox.io/s/k2mpvkr2n7

The main idea is to put the list in a separate component and change the loading state when it mounts.

For visual stuff I put a setTimeout and ignore the `cow` array (:

Comment: To me it works really cool. I've just tested with 20k items: https://codesandbox.io/s/144o3jlz27 and looks nice. I guess that the point is whether you have only one element in your render function, like this map in your solution, then `componentDidMount` will be inkoved only when this function is called. In my component I have couple of components and I guess that then `componentDidMount` is invoked just after something was rendered. Anyway as we both are not sure in 100% then maybe let's wait for more ideas from other developers :)

Comment: Sure! Good to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

1. You pass a callback prop to ItemComponent
2. This callback is called from ItemComponent's componentDidMount(),for initial render, and componentDidUpdate() for following renders.
3. The callback increments a state variable in MyWrapper
4. Loading... is displayed when this state variable equals length

Note that the state variable that counts renders should be updated using a function as a parameter, to make sure that it is incremented properly (see [this](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Initially I also was thinking about exactly the same solution but I think this is quite dirty and not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution. Ideally the concept will be what you're looking for and you can clean it up as desired.

(Also, it's my understanding that the issue is that `props.items` is huge, and that the map procedure simply takes a while)

```
class MyWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ items: this.createItemComponents() })
  }

  createItemComponents() {
    return this.props.items.length !== 0
      ? this.props.items.map(item => <ItemComponent item={item} />);
      : <p>No items to show</p>;
  }

  render() {
   <SomeLoadingIndicator active={this.state.items.length === 0} />

   <div>{this.state.items}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah, it will works properly, I also was thinking about something like that but I'm wonder if could be better solution.

Comment: Updated -- thoughts?

Comment: yeah, the issue is that `props.items` is huge. This is also why I would prefer to avoid store it in state. Please checkout @Tomas Eglinskas solution. To me it is quite cool.